# ParseUser.CurrentUser.FetchAsync() is not updating the user's data

Tags: c#, parse-platform

Everytime I call

```
user.SaveAsync(); //saving new data on user
```

I also call

```
ParseUser.CurrentUser.FetchAsync(); //update data on CurrentUser
```

But I still have the old data no matter what in my `ParseUser.CurrentUser`.
The only time `ParseUser.CurrentUser` gets updated is after logging in and/or out.

Has anyone encountered this? If so, how did you solve it?

Comment: I don't have a clue how this API works, but shouldn't you wait for the save to finish before fetching? Otherwise is seems you will fetch the old value (presuming that the save operation takes slightly longer to finish).

Comment: I do wait, of course. I was presenting you the idea. I have two separate calls, first finishes, then the other one is called.

Comment: If `user` and `CurrentUser` are the same user then can't you just do `ParseUser.CurrentUser = user`?

Comment: Because CurrentUser is read only. Is a property of ParseUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reverting the current user. This way, it will revert itself to the previous save (which should be your last user.saveasync).

```
ParseUser.CurrentUser.Revert();
```

Comment: getCurrentUser() I don't think it exists in C#, but I guess you are trying to say to make a get query on the user Id and fetch new data. I was kinda avoiding that.

Comment: And the most important thing: you cannot set ParseUser.CurrentUser, is a readOnly property.

Comment: ah gotcha. sorry. I must have been looking at the JS API.

Comment: Just tested it out. I can't believe it works. Thanks for the help, I didn't know about the Revert() method. Thanks again. You saved me a lot of work.